# When I used the matlab function 'niftiinfo',Error using affine3d Can't reload '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64/libmwcoder_types.so'

Tags: matlab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvqr4.png)
When I used the matlab function 'niftiinfo',Error using affine3d Can't reload '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64/libmwcoder_types.so'

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure the Java JRE is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Secondly, it may be possible that some dependent libraries for `libmwcoder_types.so` are missing in the system. Check if all the dependencies are present for this library by performing the following steps:

Check for missing libraries in the output

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64 
ldd libmwcoder_types.so
```

For example:

```
 libXt.so.6 => not found
 libXext.so.6 => not found
```

Install the missing libraries

If there are no missing dependencies, create a directory named `exclude` within `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64/` and put `libmwcoder_types.so` in it.